# Convert Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS iso to lxc container or download somewhere

Tags: 20.04, virtualization, lxc, lxd

Where can I find LXC version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? I can find only .iso version at: https://ubuntu.com/download/server
Or how can I convert .iso image it to LXC?

Comment: See the [official documentation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/containers-lxd) follow the instructions for installation.

Answer (score 1):

LXC and LXD use *runtimes* of Linux distributions. A *runtime* is very roughly the ISO without the Linux kernel.

At http://us.images.linuxcontainers.org/ you can see the full list of supported (provided) runtimes of many Linux distributions. Both LXC and LXD are configured to use those runtimes for you in an easy way.

If you are interested in recreating such a runtime, see [distrobuilder](https://github.com/lxc/distrobuilder). You supply a configuration file for your favorite Linux distribution ([samples here](https://github.com/lxc/lxc-ci/tree/master/images)) and then *distrobuilder* will download the necessary packages and files to create the runtime. The front page of the *distrobuilder* repository has instructions on how to create such a runtime for the Alpine Linux distribution (it's small and fast to create).